# How to update other fields but retain the user profile image?

Tags: php, laravel, breeze

I want to update the User `first_name` or `last_name` but not the profile image

Here is my profile controller:

```
/**
 * Update the user's profile information.
 */
public function update(ProfileUpdateRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $path = null;
    $request->user()->fill($request->validated());

    if ($request->user()->isDirty('email')) {
        $request->user()->email_verified_at = null;
    }

    if ($request->hasFile('image_path')){
        $path = $request->image_path->store('avatar', 'public');
    }else{

    }

    $request->user()->image_path = $path;
    $request->user()->save();

    return Redirect::route('profile.edit')->with('status', 'profile-updated');
}
```

here is my profile update controller:

```
class ProfileUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'first_name'        => ['string', 'max:255'],
            'last_name'         => ['string', 'max:255'],
            'email'             => ['email', 'max:255', Rule::unique(User::class)->ignore($this->user()->id)],
            'image_path'        => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        ];
    }
}
```

Here I want to update the other fields but I want to retain the user image.

Comment: Can you please share more from the `ProfileUpdateRequest` class?
From the code you've shared, I can only advise adding a condition within the `update` function to not include the image. But I feel like there could be a more elegant solution, that can be achieved after seeing `ProfileUpdateRequest`

Answer (score 0):

Hi since you are updating you can do this

```
 public function update(ProfileUpdateRequest $request){
   
    $user =  User::find(Auth::id());
    if(!$user){
       return response()->json(['message'=>'No User Found'],404);
    }
     if ($request->user()->isDirty('email')) {
       $user->email_verified_at = null;
    }

    if ($request->hasFile('image_path')){
        $path = $request->image_path->store('avatar', 'public');
    }

    //what happened here is that i picked the image_path from the users details gotten above
    $user->image_path = $path??$user->image_path;
    $user->email = $request->email??$user->email;
    $user->save();

    return Redirect::route('profile.edit')->with('status', 'profile-updated');
    }
```

Your request class doesn't need to have the image_path has required in it

```
class ProfileUpdateRequest extends FormRequest {
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'first_name'        => ['string', 'max:255'],
            'last_name'         => ['string', 'max:255'],
            'email'             => ['email', 'max:255', Rule::unique(User::class)->ignore($this->user()->id)],
            'image_path'        => 'nullable|file|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        ];
    } }
```

Comment: ig gaves me this error Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::update(), 1 passed in D:\My Portfolio\Laravel\Authentication\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected

Comment: can i see how your route is configured  for this particular controller ?

Comment: this is my route Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

Comment: Ok let me update the method(function) to suit your route check my answer again

Let me know if that solves your issue  thanks

Comment: now it does not updating the fields. can you specified your code im new in laravel

Comment: what error did you get now ? or no error specified

Comment: i dont get an error message. but when i updating other field. it the data does not update

Comment: Do something like `dd($request->all())` before the $user->save() and post what you get here

Comment: it does not get the user image path

Comment: i wanted to do is. if the input file has no value. i wanted the {{user->image_path}} will be the value of the input file